# AWS Glue ETL Doesn't Output All Records

Tags: aws-glue

I have an ETL script that is intended to flatten a set of 4 million JSON files using Relationalize. This script works fine on a test set of 300 files but when run on the S3 Bucket with 4 Million it only produces 1500~ output files that each contain data for a single record.

I've tried a few different configurations of this script but they all produce the same result:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.job import Job

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

# Begin variables to customize with your information
glue_source_database = "mydatabase"
glue_source_table = "mytable"
glue_temp_storage = "s3://my-data/glue_temp"
glue_relationalize_output_s3_path = "s3://my-data/glue_output/mytable_flat/"
dfc_root_table_name = "root" #default value is "roottable"
# End variables to customize with your information


datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = glue_source_database, table_name = glue_source_table, transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
dfc = Relationalize.apply(frame = datasource0, staging_path = glue_temp_storage, name = dfc_root_table_name, transformation_ctx = "dfc")
origdata = dfc.select(dfc_root_table_name)

origdataoutput = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = origdata, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": glue_relationalize_output_s3_path}, format = "json", transformation_ctx = "origdataoutput")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are only passing the root table to `glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog` . When you perform relationalize it will return a DynamicFrameCollection. To see the list of dynamic frames from this collection try printing them using `dfc.keys()` .

Refer to step 6 in [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-samples-legislators.html) and [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/glue-pivoted-data-relationalize/) to understand how relationalize works.

Comment: Having dug into it further, it still looks like Relationalize actually removes records for reasons that aren't clear. If I count the number of records in the source dynamic frames then run Relationalize and count the root table, the number is lower than the total objects in source.